# angular bootstrapping- how & when are directives compiled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, bootstrapping

I have some doubt regarding angular bootstrapping. Exactly When and how are angular directives compiled?

From angular tutorial it states 
    "Angular initializes automatically upon DOMContentLoaded event or when the    angular.js script is evaluated if at that time document.readyState is set to 'complete'"

So it means after HTML dom tree is constructed; angular loops through dom tree to evaluate elements and attach behavior to it.

For large pages is this a issue?

Any links which details step wise bootstrapping of angular elements with dom tree will also be fine!!

Comment: Most of what you are asking is well documented and too long an answer for a simple question here. Read through the documentation

Comment: Sorry being novice...Please provide which part of the documentation answers my doubt.

Comment: Read the developer guide then read the main sections of the api docs